# Weird make install : how to uninstall?

Tags: unix, makefile

For a uni course, I had to git clone a repo and build it (including monstrosities in the between) and then I had to install it. However, my teacher isn't **very good**, and the tool is pretty bad (or at least useless for my computer) and I want to revert `make install`. How do I do that ?

I forgot to do it in a virtual machine or in a docker container sadly :(

Thankies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `make uninstall` command in the build directory. The cleaner way being `make uninstall-recursive`if possible. Then do not forget to remove all sources with the `rm -rf` command.

Comment: A `make dist-clean` can be appreciated too after the `make uninstall`

Comment: So to sum up use this line `make uninstall-recursive && rm -rf <sources>`

Answer (score 0):

gmake helpfully can tell you what it would do for a given action.
The result is text, which can be translated with sed/awk/perl into other commands.
For example, if `make install` does multiple `cp <files> <destdir>/` commands, 
then the following action deletes all those files from each `destdir`:

`MAKEFLAGS= ${MAKE} -j1 -spinf $(word 1,${MAKEFILE_LIST}) install \
   | awk '/^cp /{ for (i=NF; --i>0;){print $NF"/"$i} }' | xargs rm -f`